# Looking for a shortcut to select the function/method at point

Tags: programming

I have this problem in JavaScript, but I understand the solution to it could be more general. My cursor (point) is on the name -or on the body- of a function, like this :

```js
function test() { // My cursor is here or anywhere between "function" and "}"
console.log("test");
}
```

I would like to quickly select function test, in order to move it somewhere else in the code, or remove it completely. Is there a function, in js2-mode or anywhere else, which would allow me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this part](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-by-Defuns.html) of the manual. Marking with <kbd>C-M-h</kbd> should work just fine. This runs `mark-defun` and marks the complete current function definition around point.

Some nifty details:

- If your mark was already active, it extends the region until the end of the next defun.
- A negative argument reverses the direction of traver for all subsequent calls. So by default without previous calls to `mark-defun` this selects the previous defun.

Comment: Thanks for the useful manual link!

Comment: Please explain what that keybinding does to make this a complete answer.

Answer (score 6):

Emacs calls a function definition a “defun”, because `defun` is the keyword¹ that starts a function definition starts in Lisp. [Commands to move by defuns](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-by-Defuns.html) use the modifiers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>:

- `C-M-a` and `C-M-e` to move to the beginning/end of the current function definition;
- `C-M-h` to select the current function definition.

This is somewhat similar, but not strictly parallel, to `M-a` and `M-e` to move to the beginning/end of the current sentence, and `M-h` to select the current paragraph.

The exact behavior of these commands depend on the programming language. The default rule is that a defun starts with a line with 0 indentation, but many programming language modes change this, either by tuning the way the default function works or by binding the usual keyboard shortcuts to a different function.

On a related note, Emacs calls a [subexpression a “sexp”](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html#Expressions). Generally a sexp is delimited by balanced parentheses, brackets or braces, or is a single identifer. Again the exact rules depend on the programming language. The main commands for sexps are:

- `C-M-b` and `C-M-f` to move back/forward to the previous/next sexp.
- `C-M-p` and `C-M-n` to move back/forward to the previous/next expression delimited by parentheses (the exact rules depend on the language, but typically this stops in fewer places than `C-M-b` and `C-M-f`).
- `C-M-u` (`M-x backward-up-list`) and `M-x up-list` (no default binding) to move out of the [surrounding parentheses/brackets/braces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-by-Parens.html#Moving-by-Parens).
- `C-M-SPC` or `C-M-@` to select the following sexp.

¹  <sub>Not a keyword, strictly speaking, but close enough.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it. Use `C-M h`, which is bound to `mark-defun`.

The beauty of it is that it works not only on JavaScript, but also on Python, Elisp, or seemingly any other language. I found the solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1268693/9450152) which is specific to C.

Answer (score 1):

Install `evil`, `evil-matchit`, then press `%`. It supports many programming language, not just javascript. It can be extended easily by user to support new syntax and new languages.